# Importing OFX files

Tags: c#, currency, ofx

I am trying to import financial information using the OFX protocol which is used by Quicken and Money. I have had a pretty good look around for an open source library but so far have come up empty.

Does anyone know of anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[GnuCash](http://www.gnucash.org/) can do it, and it looks like they use [LibOFX](http://libofx.sourceforge.net/).

Also, there are some python scripts and OFX resources [here](http://www.jongsma.org/gc/).

Answer (score 1):

How about ["Class to transform ofx (Microsoft Money) file into DataSet"](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/Ofx_to_DataSet.aspx)?

Note I'm not hugely familiar with OFX - that is just a quick search result...

Answer (score 0):

PocketSense is written in Python, and fetches OFX from servers into Microsoft Money.